# Multiple enumitem global setups

Tags: enumitem

(I am sure somebody should have asked this before, but I cannot find it.)

Is it possible to name `enumitem` global setups, so that one can define multiple global setups and refer them by name?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{labelsep=*, leftmargin=1.5pc}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[align=left,
   leftmargin=0pt,
   labelindent=\parindent,
   listparindent=\parindent,
   labelwidth=0pt,
   itemindent=!,
   label=\alph*)]

\item test
\item test

\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=\parindent]
    \item test
    \item test
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just define a separate environment for each of your common configurations using  `\newlist`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{enumerate1}{enumerate}{4}% new enumerate-like environment
\setlist[enumerate1]{% settings for enumerate1
    labelsep=*,
    leftmargin=1.5pc,
    label=\arabic*)
}
\newlist{enumerate2}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[enumerate2]{
    align=left,
    leftmargin=0pt,
    labelindent=\parindent,
    listparindent=\parindent,
    labelwidth=0pt,
    itemindent=!,
    label=\alph*)
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{enumerate1}
    \item test
    \item test
  \end{enumerate1}

  \begin{enumerate2}
    \item test
    \item test
  \end{enumerate2}

\end{document}
```

Of course, rather than `enumerate1` and `enumerate2`, ... you can -- and should -- call them whatever you like, so you can choose more suggestive/informative names.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\SetEnumitemKey` to define a style key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{labelsep=*, leftmargin=1.5pc}
\SetEnumitemKey{mystyle}{align=left,
   leftmargin=0pt,
   labelindent=\parindent,
   listparindent=\parindent,
   labelwidth=0pt,
   itemindent=!,
   label=\alph*)}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item test
\item test

\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[mystyle]
    \item test
    \item test
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]